# nginx how to configure nginx to nevigate to a subpage for reactjs app

Tags: redirects, nginx, localhost, reverse-proxy

I have following nginx setup where I used proxy configuration to redirect my landing page (built with reactjs) to my domain, say (`www.example.com`), here is my nginx configuration

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name www.example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}

........
........

}
```

no problem with the above configuration if I request on `www.example.com`, it give me the redirected web page(my landing page) hosted on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. But if I try to navigate to a sub page like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders`, what should I do then? I tried the following

```
location /orders {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders;
}
```

but it's not working if I request on `www.example.com/orders`, its always redirect me into the `www.example.com` (landing page), i.e `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

Answer (score 2):

This is my way of handling routes in reactjs and nginx
I send every path to index.html and as a result reactjs is responsible for routes, and for that purpose I use [reactrouter](https://reactrouter.com/)

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Comment: You are suggesting that they remove the reverse proxy altogether and deploy the react files directly under a directory served by nginx?

Comment: yes I do, is that wrong?

Comment: No, it is a good idea.  But maybe you could expand your answer to say that explicitly.   Maybe also explain why that is better than the reverse proxy.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand why he needs to use different ports for the domain and react app. Here is a good tutorial on deploying a reactjs application with nginx.
[link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your answer to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice.  Editing updates into your answer ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to use your answer sees them.

Comment: My guess is that they think they need to reverse proxy to the dev server that runs with react and don't know about better ways to deploy.